# Is it possible to execute a SQL Injection if a parameter contains no single quotes and is then sorrounded by single quotes?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, sql-injection

Is a SQL Injection still possible if a parameter is parsed so as to remove all single quotes contained and then it's surrounded by single quotes? I know how this is bad looking and generally talking is much better to use a Prepared Statement but, for the sake of curiousness, I would like to know if there's a way or even better an example on how to deal damage to a database if the parameters are treaded as following:

```
String nativeQuery = "INSERT INTO USER (NAME) VALUES (' " + username.replace("'", "") + "')";
EntityManager em = getEm();
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(nativeQuery);
query.executeUpdate();
```

I did not found any resource online that explains this specific case, seems to be impossible to execute any command from within a String, can someone confirm that? An answer is appreciated even the used dialect is not present in tags at bottom.

Comment: Use [`preparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and then `setString`. It will pass the data, not the SQL text with injection

Comment: There is a way to do it with EntityManager? Creating the Query object I can only set parameters, there's no way to set the String.

Comment: I do not know java, and cannot tell you how to do this with EntityManager. But the basic principle is the same for any language and any RDBMS: prepare a call (that is SQL parsing and building the query plan), bind variables (that is passing the data as input/output parameters for the call) and then execute (perform the actual execution)